# Elasticsearch Error "bootstrap checks failed" (Binding non-loopback address)

Tags: elasticsearch

Recently, after installation of Elasticsearch 7.3.2, I found out that the server is working fine when bound to the localhost or 127.0.0.1.

But I made it available for external use, that is on particular IP or 0.0.0.0, it raised me error and stopped the server:

> bound or publishing to a non-loopback address, enforcing
>   bootstrap checks
>       [2019-09-19T18:21:43,962][ERROR][o.e.b.Bootstrap          ] [MARFEEN] node validation exception
>       [1] bootstrap checks failed

Comment: @OpsterElasticsearchNinja If you see, I had already resolved the issue myself and accepted my own answer long ago.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Could not get any answer on this solution, most of them were related to max opened file limits. But it was solved when I enabled a config property `discovery.seed_hosts` in elasticsearch.yml file:

```
# ---------------------------------- Network -----------------------------------
#
# Set the bind address to a specific IP (IPv4 or IPv6):
#
network.host: 0.0.0.0
#
# Set a custom port for HTTP:
#
#http.port: 9200
#
# For more information, consult the network module documentation.
#
# --------------------------------- Discovery ----------------------------------
#
# Pass an initial list of hosts to perform discovery when this node is started:
# The default list of hosts is ["127.0.0.1", "[::1]"]
#
discovery.seed_hosts: ["127.0.0.1"]
```

After enabling the above property, it worked fine on non-loopback host also.

Comment: This really worked! Just so it helps someone else, I had following error in the test es master node (single node) log:
[2020-03-11T00:03:53,259][INFO ][o.e.b.BootstrapChecks    ] [esmaster] bound or publishing to a non-loopback address, enforcing bootstrap checks
[2020-03-11T00:03:53,284][ERROR][o.e.b.Bootstrap          ] [esmaster] node validation exception

Comment: Thanks. Out of many answers, finally this worked for me on windows server

Answer (score 4):

Most of the users don't know that setting `network.host: 0.0.0.0` will cause the production bootstrap check and this is the cause of failure as mentioned in the below line of the error message.

> [o.e.b.Bootstrap ] [MARFEEN] node validation exception [1] bootstrap
> checks failed

**In order, to resolve the issue when you are running Elasticsearch in development mode or with a single node, please add below config in (Elasticsearch.config) to avoid above mentioned checks**.

```
discovery.type: single-node --> In case of single node Elasticsearch cluser

es.enforce.bootstrap.checks=false. --> Explicitly disable these checks in Non-production env.
```

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is correct. This is set this way so that the health check forces your configuration to be presenting an external address before the node comes online.

The way you have configured it will work, so long as you do not require any special cluster conditions. At that point, you will need to set `network.host:` to an external IP/hostname.